# lock parent window from scrolling when modal is displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to prevent the user from scrolling the parent window when a modal is displayed over it.

It is an issue when users view the modal on a iPad, when they click and drag outside of the content div or scrollbar within the modal, then it scrolls the (parent) page below it.

I think once the modal is opened, I can add some css to the body tag or main container to disable scrolling by giving it a overflow: hidden; and removing it once the modal is closed. Any suggestions are welcomed, thanks.

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="#" class="open-modal">Open modal</a>
  <div class="modal">Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: I used this http://www.bcreatives.com.au/blog/enabledisable-scrolling-in-iphoneipads-safari-browser.html to disable it on iOS devices and also added overflow: hidden; to the body and removed it when the user closed the modal.

Comment: You can try `window.onscroll` event and check if the modal is opened just use `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow:hidden;` or any classname with this property on body for cut content when modal is show and remove css/class when modal is hidden.

```
html, body{height:100%}
.customClass{overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: AFAIK, doesn't avoid the DIV to be scrolled in chrome (safari?) using e.g mousewheel. Now that's quite depending OP's situation

Comment: I did this and also added overflow: hidden; for it to work in desktop browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent `mousewheel` listner from executing by using following code

When modal open:

```
$('body').on('wheel.modal mousewheel.modal', function () {return false;});
```

When modal close:

```
$('body').off('wheel.modal mousewheel.modal');
```

Comment: @Brad I am not sure on that

Comment: This ended up working for the iPad, http://www.bcreatives.com.au/blog/enabledisable-scrolling-in-iphoneipads-safari-browser.html